# Add distinct context for vote tabs for localization purpose

Tags: bug, profile-page, localization, votes-tab

For translation purposes, we need different translations for the same words, in particular on  the [user profile page on votes tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=all):

> [image]

At least the "Undelete" and "Reopen" should have different translations from the ones used as links below the question body, if applicable.

It's already implemented for [Undelete](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5EUndelete%24):

> [image]

[Specific to Votes tab](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/11935):

> [image]

But for some reason, it's not implemented for ["Reopen"](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5EReopen%24). We currently have the only one:

> [image]

In general, it's better to add such context, i.e. REFERS_TO variant to all tab names here.

Linked question on ruSO.meta: [Требуется разделение контекстов для голосов и действий с сообщением](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4679/176217)